# Nested iterators access

Tags: c++

I have a question about iterators.The question is:" How can I access ( if it's a nested iterator ) the element in row, that is higher or below.Here's an example what I mean:

```
for( auto i = graphMatrix.begin();i != graphMatrix.end();i++ )
{
    for( auto j = i->begin();j != i->end();j++ )
    {
        if( *j == 'O' )
        {
          // here we must analyze an element which is a row higher or lower
        }
    }
}
```

Next thing is what I wanted to do ( but it's with vector ):

```
 for( int i = graphMatrix.size();i < graphMatrix.size();i++ )
{
    for( int j = graphMatrix.size();j < graphMatrix.size();j++ )
    {
        if( graphMatrix[i][j] == 'O' )
        {
           graphMatrix[j][i] == 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

I know that vector has fast size function, but to generalize the code, in my mind, it's better to use iterators ( as my mentor said ).So how can I do the same stuff with iterators as with vectors?

Comment: You could store the value you need in a temporary variable.

But it will be a headache to read / debug so the approach using indices is probably the best (I doubt that iterators would be much faster in this case).

Comment: "it's better to use iterators"... for iteration. You're doing something other than iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since iterators are non-numeric, they are not well-suited to this problem.

You can write complex, confusing and possibly costly code with `std::distance` and `std::advance`, performing "pointer arithmetic" on your iterators... or you can stick with your numeric loop counters approach, which is precisely what I'd do. Especially seeing as you're using `vector`s, which have constant-time (and, let's face it, *immediate*) access to arbitrary elements in arbitrary positions.

If you're wondering why, in this case, iterators are suddenly not the "better" mechanism for iteration that you've been taught they are: it's because *one must use the correct tool for the job*, and no technology is the correct tool for *all* jobs.

Answer (score 0):

to get the position of you vector from the iterator with `std::distance`:

```
for( auto i = graphMatrix.begin();i != graphMatrix.end();i++ )
{
    for( auto j = i->begin();j != i->end();j++ )
    {
        int x = std::distance(graphMatrix.begin(),i);
        int y = std::distance(i->begin(),j);

        graphMatrix[x][y] = 'x';


    }
}
```

Comment: ... and then use the numeric indices anyway? What's the point in that?! :-)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit in this example there is no point, but that was not question as far as i understood, there are places where the use of std::distance might be required in such a context,